# Red5 Server Recording issue

Tags: flash, red5, x264

I am Trying to publishing a rtmp stream encoded with x264 Lib. the stream is recording but I am trying to connect a flash client to play this stream the stream is not working many times but when I am finishing the recording and try to connect this stream the stream is wirking well. Can any body help Me . My media server is Red 5 Server. I am using the Java based Recording Client. And the Player is based on Flash.

Answer (score 0):

The file is not available for playback while recording; to view the stream you'd have to play the live stream.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your Answer, But in the Stream folder, when I was starting recording file is creating, but  when I was trying to play it live file was not plying and some time it si playing with a long delay.